# Uniformization of a plane minus cantor set

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk endowed with the Poincaré metric and $G$ be a Fuchsian group such that the hyperbolic surface $\mathbb{D}/G$ is homeomorphic to the plane minus a Cantor set.

**Question:  Is there a conformal bijection between $\mathbb{D}/G$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus K$ for some Cantor set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$?**

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes but the version of the uniformization theorem I know doesn't imply this (just that the plane minus any Cantor set can be uniformized by some Fuchsian group $G$).   Any good references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Koebe Uniformisation theorem says any planar Riemann surface is biholomorphic to a domain in the Riemann sphere .

Comment: Any good reference?

Comment: See for example George Springer's book on Riemann surfaces

Comment: Thanks! I'd accept this as an answer.  If it were an answer... which it is.  Anyway, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Koebe uniformisation theorem says that any planar Riemann surface is biholomorphic to a domain in the Riemann sphere .See George Springer's book on Riemann surfaces.At the risk of self promotion you can also look at my book with T Napier titled An Introduction to Riemann Surfaces .